# Heroku pricing dramatically increases when using microservices architecture

Tags: heroku, microservices

I'm just starting with Heroku, and I'm considering using it to host my app.

The problem is, I'm planning to build my app with a micro services architecture.

As I understand Heroku's pricing, they charge per dyno. When using micro services, there are a bunch of "apps" or "services" working together to provide the functionality of one app.

It seems inevitable to do this without using multiple dynos, and by adding dynos, the price goes up very quickly.

I have three questions: 
Is my interpretation of Heroku's pricing correct?
Is there a better way to do a micro services architecture using Heroku?
Or, is there a way to deploy multiple docker containers on a single dyno?

Comment: Not related to Heroku pricing, but I believe it's kinda industry-wide consensus that it's more economically to do monolith-first instead of microservices-first: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html -- i suppose you're doing it for learning, but i'm mentioning it just in case ;)

Comment: Hmm...I didn't realize that. Thanks for telling me. I think what we'll do is design the Monolith in such a way that it is easy to split up later, and then if we ever get more money we can switch over.

Comment: Yup, that's wiser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Heroku costs will definitely go up as you use more dynos and more apps, but if you are just starting out, the money you spend will be in no way more than the time you would spend setting up something like AWS to perform the same functionality.

You can always save money later, once your app is running and users are loving it. If you goal is to prototype and get it out fast, Heroku is still the best choice.

Did you know about [Heroku price calculator](https://www.heroku.com/pricing)?

Saw you run 10*1x dynos, plus some other services, like text messages and such. That will cost you $250-350 this month. That's a lot, sure. But you can get your app running tomorrow, and presumably that is worth a lot more than 250.

Comment: Perhaps, but I do have 6 months to build the app. It's not just me, it's a group, and money is our most limited resource as of right now. My first choice would have been GCP, but it's too expensive. That's what made Heroku appealing to me.

Comment: It's not too bad actually. I don't need the text messaging service at all. I might need ClearDB MySQL add-on, but that's free. I think I only need three dynos, maybe four, so (using the Hobby plan), that brings me to around $250 for a whole year. Then again, GCP was somewhere around there anyway...

Comment: GCP is excellent too. I am a big fan of Firebase tools specifically, they are making them better and better every quarter. At the end of the day it's a trade off on how much time you want to spend configuring and navigating the more complex infra. For example, I have a friend who makes $100 revenue per database entry, so he doesn't care how much Heroku costs, as long as he doesn't have to think. Each project is diff.

Comment: Yea, Firebase could satisfy all my needs for free actually. But this is more of a learning project, so we want to use a Python Flask app with a SQL database. I'm thinking I might just put it all in one dyno. If our app gets enough money, we can upgrade and use multiple dynos with the microservices architecture. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: You could also checkout pythonanywhere

Comment: Usually there will be a lot of unforeseen extra costs so 250 - 350$ is a lot for most people with normal salary :-(